# ImageView of TableView

Tags: ios, image, uitableview

Till 2 days I am trying to load from a plist file a some images into my table view rows. I created the NSMutableArray when I added this line 
`cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[images objectAtIndex:row]];` to the "cellForRowAtIndexPath" method before the return, xcode gives me this error:
Use of undeclared identifier 'cell' and Incompatible pointer to integer conversion sending double to parameter of type NSUInteger.

What is the problem?

Comment: A little bit of code could be helpfull

Comment: try this NSString *CellIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",indexPath.row];

UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

Comment: @Venkat Manohar I tried your code bot there is no image.

Comment: I also tried  this cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[images objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]; but there is an error on the "cell" word. 
I did the same thing for the lable of the row from a plist and it works perfectly! For this i have this line:  RowContent.textLabel.text = [texts objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; but if I use this line for the images it doesn't work!

Comment: Can you post your cellForRowAtIndexPath method here. We might be able to help that way.

Answer (score 0):

add these,

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier =@"Cell";

   UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
```

Comment: do i need to add this line to the cellForRowtIndexPath? it doesn't work with this line

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the second part where "**Incompatible pointer to integer conversion sending double to parameter of type NSUInteger**". Check the data type of `row`. If it is not `NSUInteger` you can not use that as `[images objectAtIndex:row]`. Try `[images objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]` instead of that. And regarding the first issue, I agree to the above comment that `cell` is not declared and initialized. You need to declare it and allocate memory.